# Publishing asp.net mvc website to windows container giving error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, docker, visual-studio-2017, windows-container

I am trying to publish basic mvc site to windows container. I get error when trying to run image in detach mode. I am able to build image and can see image when I run following command

```
 docker images
```

Commands to run image

```
 # This line is successful
 docker build -t mvcaspnet . 

 # Error after line mentioned below
 docker run -d --name mvcaspnet1 mvcaspnet
```

Error I get when I run is

docker: Error response from daemon: container c0899809... encountered an error during Start: failure in a Windows system call: The operation timed out because a response was not received from the Virtual Machine hosting the Container. (0xc0370109).

Docker info

```
Containers: 3
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 3
Images: 2
Server Version: 17.03.0-ce
Storage Driver: windowsfilter
 Windows:
Logging Driver: json-file
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: l2bridge l2tunnel nat null overlay transparent
Swarm: inactive
Default Isolation: hyperv
Kernel Version: 10.0 14393 (14393.953.amd64fre.rs1_release_inmarket.170303-1614)
Operating System: Windows 10 Pro
OSType: windows
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 4
Total Memory: 3.803 GiB
Name: .....
ID: .....
Docker Root Dir: C:\ProgramData\Docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): true
 File Descriptors: -1
 Goroutines: 18
 System Time: 2017-03-26T20:15:08.4131848+01:00
 EventsListeners: 0
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Experimental: true
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
```

Comment: Can you run just plain `docker run -d microsoft/aspnet`

Comment: @GSA same error The operation timed out because a response was not received from the Virtual Machine hosting the Container. (0xc0370109).

Comment: what `docker info` shows

Comment: Update question with docker info

Comment: Try to switch to non-experimental build. There is nothing appears to be wrong about your setup. Also I believe you are a version behind in docker setup. Mine states `Server Version: 17.03.1-ce-rc1`

Answer (score 1):

Not sure which ASP.NET image you are using to build your image, but [here](http://passionatecoder.ca/Article/Deploying-ASPNET-and-SQL-SERVER-application-using-Windows-Containers-on-Azure) is how I did using docker compose as I need IIS and SQL Server and it is working as expected.